# FosUserBundle registration validation new image field

Tags: symfony, registration, fosuserbundle, custom-fields

I am using FOSUserBundle and i have problem with validation user entity.

In my user entity i have:

```
    /**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize="3M",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"}
 * )
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="profile_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 *
 * @var File $image
 */
protected $image;
```

What is good but this makes me damn not working WHILE REGISTRATION: "* @Assert\NotBlank()" What is absolutly correct because i dont fill image while registration.

While user register, in controller is first condition: if ($process) { // what is actually if form is valid) and because there is no image its not valid...

My question is...

I have succesfully overriden RegistrationFormHandler file but now... HOW TO MODIFY IT? Or what to do .. maybe in some other file?

```
    public function process($confirmation = false)
{
    $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
    $this->form->setData($user);

    if ('POST' == $this->request->getMethod()) {
        $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);
        if ($this->form->isValid()) {

            // do your custom logic here

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I think something like... exception for registration validation for this field or something like that? IDK
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

### use validation groups ...

[validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#validation-groups) make it possible to validate against different combinations of constraints.

In your case use a validation group i.e. 'registration' ( not containing the image/notblank constraints) for the signup form and another validation group i.e. 'profile' for your profile-edit form.